# XCode 15 Cocoapod Firebase Missing required module 'GTMSessionFetcherCore'

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, xcode15

**XCode: 15.3**

- Build configuration: Release.
- platform :ios, '13.0'.

**Cocoapods: v1.15.2**

- Podfile.

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (5.9.0)
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing Firebase (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseABTesting (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseDatabase (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseDynamicLinks (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (10.23.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreInternal (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseInAppMessaging (10.22.0-beta)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseRemoteConfig (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseSessions (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseSharedSwift (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseStorageUI (13.1.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (3.3.1)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (10.22.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.4.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.13.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.4.0)
Installing PromisesSwift (2.4.0)
Installing RecaptchaInterop (100.0.0)
Installing SDWebImage (5.19.0)
Installing abseil (1.20220623.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.49.1)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.49.1)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.4)
Installing nanopb (2.30910.0)
```

I've got an error after building this project.
You can see that error below.
I checked release notes from Firebase but I couldn't figure out what is wrong.
That error doesn't occur when the build configuration turned into Debug, though.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_10221_-_march_7_2024

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQwRl.png)

Someone solved the problem related to the macro of Cocoapods.
But it didn't work to me which is I tried to remove the macro of Cocoapods like this

```
// #if COCOAPODS
//   import GTMSessionFetcher
// #else
  import GTMSessionFetcherCore
// #endif
```